# Can I make my Router (DD-WRT) act as DHCP server for an unmanaged switch that is not connected to it?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dd-wrt

```
+-------------+                        +----------------------+                     
|             |                        |                      |       +------------+
| Cable Modem +----------+-------------+ ASUS (DD-WRT) Router +-------+ Computer 1 |
|             |          |             |                      |       +------------+
+-------------+          |             +----------------------+                     
                         |                                                          
                         |                                                          
                         |             +----------------------+                     
                         |             |                      |       +------------+
                         +-------------+ Unmanaged Switch     +-------+ Computer 2 |
                                       |                      |       +------------+
                                       +----------------------+
```

I would like to have Computer 2 get DHCP from the ASUS Router. Right now I can't get internet connection from Computer 2 because it can't get an IP address.  I currently have the following setup at home.  I used to have the Unmanaged switch behind my router and everything used to work well, but because of the building setup I had to separate the two.

Is there a way to make the DD-WRT router act as the DHCP server for everything connect to the router as well as the unmanaged switch?

Comment: How exactly is the cable modem connected to both the router and the switch? The cable modem has more than one ethernet interface?

Comment: Do you have the "right" to a second ip?

Comment: As it is, you're trying to get 2 IP addresses from one service; that's not going to work. Are you trying to set up a DMZ? If so, the best way would be to add a 3rd NIC to the Asus & hang the switch from that. Then you can control access to each network individually, whilst providing DHCP from the Asus to both independent structures. [That's assuming DD-WRT can do that, I'm not experienced with it]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess you could setup the DHCP server to advertise on the WAN interface but that is a less than perfect idea. However it would allow you to lease addresses to the other "network".

A better idea would be to attach the unmanaged switch to back of the ASUS on "port 2" doing so would allow you to advertise the DHCP server on the LAN side of your network and still give addresses to the computer hanging off the switch.

Does that make sense?